# What is the easiest way to copy a database from one Informix IDS 11 Server to another

Tags: migration, rdbms, informix, administration

The source database is quite large. The target database doesn't grow automatically. They are on different machines.

I'm coming from a MS SQL Server, MySQL background and IDS11 seems overly complex (I am sure, with good reason).

Comment: A significant update had been added to IDS with 11.70, that is using `ontape` with STDIO. So it would be important to know which minor version of IDS you are referring to.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few choices.

dbexport/dbimport
onunload/onload
HPL (high performance loader) options.

I have personally used onunload/onload and dbexport/dbimport.  I have not used HPL.  I'm using IDS 10.

**onunload/onload** [IBM docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mig.doc/mig138.htm)

Back up the raw database to disk or tape in page size chunks

faster (especially if you go to disk)

Issues if the the database servers are on different operating systems or hardware or if they just have different page sizes.

**dbexport/dbimport**  [IBM docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mig.doc/mig138.htm)

backup the database in delimited ascii files

writes an ascii schema of the database including all users, tables, views, indexes, etc. Everything about the structure of the database into one huge plain text file.

separate plain text files for each table of the database as well

not so fast

issues on dbimport on any table that has bad data, any view with incorrect syntax, etc.  (This can be a good thing, an opportunity to identify and clean)

***DO NOT LEAVE THIS TAPE ON THE FRONT SEAT OF YOUR CAR WHEN YOU RUN INTO THE STORE FOR AN ICE CREAM (or you'll be on the news).***  Also read ... Not a very secure way to be moving data around. :)

***Limitation:*** Requires exclusive access to the source database.

Here is a good place to start in the docs --> [Migration of Data Between Database Servers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mig.doc/mig138.htm)

Comment: Be wary of onunload and onload.  Certainly, they should only be used on binary-compatible hardware, and only with the same version of the DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

One way to move data from one server to another is to backup the database using the dbexport command.

Then after copying the backup files to the destination server run the dbimport command.

To create a new database you need to create the DBSpace for the new database using the onmonitor tool, at this point you could use the existing files from the other server.

You will then need to create the database on the destination server using the dbaccess tool. The dbaccess tool has a database option that allows you to create a database. When creating the database you specify what DBSpace to use.

The source database may be made up of many chunks which you will also need to copy and attach to the new database.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is dbexport/dbimport, as others have mentioned.

The fastest way is using onpload, the High Performance Loader. If you have lots of data, but not a ridiculous number of tables, this is definitely worth pursuing. There are some bits and pieces on the IIUG site that may be of assistance in scripting the HPL to generate all the config you'll need.

Answer (score 1):

have you used the export tool ?  There used to be a way if you first put the db's into quiescent mode and then you could actually copy the DBSpaces across (dbspaces tool I think... its been a few years now).

Because with informix you used to be able to specify the DBSpaces(s) to used for the table (maybe even in the alter table ?).

Check - dbaccess tool - there is an export command.
Put the DB's into quiesent mode or shut down, copy the dbspaces and then attach table telling it to point to the new dbspaces file.  (the dbspaces tool could be worth while looking at.. I have manuals around here.  they are 9.2, but it shouldn't have changed too much).

Answer (score 1):

If both the machines use the same version of IDS then another option would be to use ontape to take a backup on one machine one machine and restore on another. You can use the STDIO option and then just stream the backup onto the other machine where the restore could just restore from the STDIO.

From the "Data Replication for High Availability and Distribution" redbook:

```
ontape -s -L 0 -F | rsh secondary_server "ontape –p"
```

You could also create a passwordless ssh connection b/w the hosts and transfer in a more secure way.

Comment: Shouldn't one need to use `-t STDIO` to do so?